# How to rename a partition name in mysql 5.6.16

Tags: mysql, rename, partition

I'm using mysql 5.6.16 and now want to change a partition name. I cannot find rename partition syntax, and it is inefficient to use statement as below:

```
alter table name reorganize partition old into ( partition new ...).
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it by the way of exchange pasrtition. Firstly, I exchange the data in the partition to a normal empty table, Secondly, I reorganize the empty partition to wanted name. Finally, I exhchange the data with the normal table again